# rendering of decimal not same in debug and published version

Tags: .net, iis-6, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have an application developped using mvc 5.1 and dot net framework 4.5.  Recently I observed that the datatype `decimal` is not being rendered the same way when running in debug mode in visual studio 2013 and published mode.  By that I mean, if I have a value of `34.50`, in debug mode, it renders it as `34.50` whereas the same is being rendered as `34,50` when published.  Please note that in the

> Windows 8 >  settings> region > Format customize format

I have `'.'` as decimal.

Can anyone guide what could be causing this issue and how can I solve it?

---

Latest updates

I recently downloaded I recently downloaded the music store version from asp.net site.  I upgraded that project from mvc3 to mvc using visual studio 2012.

I ran it from vs 2012, and it rendered the decimals as '.'

I then published it  and there it was rendered as ','

From that, I can deduce that the issue is not related to mvc5

Since it uses mvc4, I had to use .net v4.5 for the application pool

Comment: Could you have a config transform that is changing the locale settings?

Comment: Do you publish it on another computer?

Comment: I saw there was a windows update and it started behaving like that afterwards. My colleague too had same issue as me.  Yes, the application is running on the server and there, it still displays the '.'.  I guess there hasn`t been any update yet there

Comment: If you want it to always use a specific culture, why don't you just specify that in code? It would be simpler than getting user settings synced, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say "Copy to systems accounts etc" if there is an application pool that already exists it does not copy those settings to that account. So basically for some reason it does not copy the settings to existing application pool user accounts. So I created a new application pool and that solved the issue